# Custom Javascript button for Lightning Action

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

After going through Trailhead and various other blogs I was under the impression that Javascript buttons are not supported in Lightning. But what I am not able to understand is that why/how I am able to map a Javascript button under Lightning Experience Actions in the page layout? What I am missing here?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll want to double-check your button. Odds are, this is a Visualforce page instead.

Comment: Sorry, I may not be clear in my post. Yes, this a detail page button which is redirecting to a VF page on the click. So you meant to say that will be supported under Lightning Action?

Comment: I also found from the Salesforce that this is supported in Lightning. Thanks for your response.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_links_constructing.htm

Comment: Not sure if you're looking for this. Javascript buttons are being phased out by SFDC. You might want to look at [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Hyperlink-Formula-Fields-for-JavaScript-Disablement&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trailhead modules, Salesforce documentation, and countless resources online are all correct. The JavaScript buttons ("OnClick behavior") are not supported in Lightning Experience, and will not be available in the future. The Visualforce and URL buttons will continue to be supported for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Faced similar issue .  SF shall do a better job by retire the configuration on  Lightning Experience so it wont confuse the admin who try to use this function or configuration, or at least pop up some error message to warn admin when we try use this function . 

This poor design cause issue to admin , when admin  so setup correctly , spent some hours troubleshoot then only find out that this is a limitation , they are leaving their defects alive and not proper close it or handle it